# Example source code for an ActiveX control to upload files

Tags: activex

I'm wanting to build an ActiveX control to upload files from a user's machine on a web page.

Where can I fnd a good example or tutorial for this - I guess C++ would be my preferred language, but VB would be OK too.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveX is a dead technology. I can't think of a good reason to use it instead of Silverlight.

I've actually written one in Silverlight myself. You can see it on my website if you want to take a look.

Comment: Yes, I know ActiveX is a "dead" technology, but it does have some advantages for my scenario - uploading multiple files.

Comment: Silverlight is capable of this as well. I cannot emphasize enough that you should avoid ActiveX.

Comment: OK, let me state my exact requirements.
This is in an intranet environment, and actually a Silverlight LOB app.
The user wants to configure a location in the file system for upload and download of files. The Silverlight app needs to communicate with the ActiveX control to save or load files from this location. This is NOT possible in Silverlight.

I know there are issues around security, etc. But it seems that ActiveX is really the only viable technology for this, at least until Silverlight has some ability to do this via some trust setting.

Comment: Craig, have you considered Flash's file upload capabilities? Or Java?